# Missing HTML elements to be hidden or shown

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I've implemented a chat application using `socket-io` and `nodejs`. The application is running fine but, sometimes, I'm facing problems to treat `HTML` content because when I try to `$('#id').hide()` or `$('#id').show()` nothing happens because the element *id* is not available.

If I try to refresh page pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, sometimes it works because that element is rendered before I try to hide or show it.  I got this behavior while debugging using Google Developer tools but I'm not sure if it's the "real why".

I was trying to find on Internet what is the life cycle of DOM elements but I didn't find something that could clarify my thoughts.

I'm trying to reproduce this problem on development environment but I'm pretty far of reach the problem:

```
<script>
    console.log('Creating socket');
    var socket = io();
    console.log('Socket created');
    socket.on('connected', function (data) {
        console.log('connected to server');
    }); 

    function timeout() {
        setTimeout(function() {console.log('sleeping')}, 5000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        timeout(); // is possible to stuck process on this point?
        console.log('Ready');
    });
</script>
```

No matter where I put `socket.on('connected'..` because it's always called after `console.log('Ready')`. Based on this, my theory of <kbd>F5</kbd> refresh is not correct and I feel that I'm running in circles.

Anyone have an idea why `HTML` elements are not present sometimes?

And, If I use `socket.on('anyevent, {})` inside `$(document).ready(function(){}` do I have any guarantee that the event will only be processed after page being full rendered?

On a real world, all our sockets events are inside  `$(document).ready(function(){}` but still not hiding or showing some html elements because they aren't present.

Comment: wait! if the element (`id`) is not present, what do you expect to happen? (if it's not present you cannot show or hide it) - can you elaborate on the expected functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your HTML and code structure but this sounds like you are binding your event listeners to a dynamically added element but this element does not exist at the time of the binding.

If my understanding is correct, you need to add the binding on an element but base the action on the newly added element, something along the lines of:

```
   // Add event listener, bound to the dynamically added element
   $("button").on('click', $("#newElemId"), function(){
       // if element exists, toggle it
       if($("#newElemId").length){
           $("#newElemId").toggle();
       }else{
          console.log('element not present yet');
       }
   });
```

**See demo below:**

```js
$(function(){

   // define function to add an element to the DOM
   var addElement = function(){
       var newElementAsObj = $(document.createElement('div'));
       // add an id for querying later
       newElementAsObj.attr('id', 'newElemId');
       // add some text (so it's visible)
       newElementAsObj.text('New Element');       
       $("#container").append(newElementAsObj);
       console.log('new element added!');
   }
   
   // add a new element after a few secs
   setTimeout( addElement, 5 * 1000); // time is in ms so 5*1000 = 5secs
     
   // Add event listener, bound to the dynamically added element
   $("button").on('click', $("#newElemId"), function(){
       if($("#newElemId").length){
           // if element exists, toggle it
           $("#newElemId").toggle();
       }else{
          console.log('element not present yet');
       }
   });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
<button>Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    timeout(); // is possible to stuck process on this point?
    console.log('Ready');
});
```

No, it's not possible. But you don't need to wait there. You can remove that `timeout` function entirely.

You should move the `socket.on('connected', function ...` into `$(document).ready(...` because you don't want to respond to any socket events until the document is ready.

```
<script>
    console.log('Creating socket');
    var socket = io(); // It's fine to do this before the document loads
    console.log('Socket created');

    $(document).ready(function(){
        socket.on('connected', function (data) {
            console.log('connected to server');
        });
        console.log('waiting for connection...');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery documentation describes that you can use `$(window).on('load', function() {})` to run your code after the entire page, not just the DOM, is ready. You might try that if it's not enough that only your DOM is ready, but you need to wait for the whole page to be loaded.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

> If I try to refresh page pressing F5, sometimes it works because that element is rendered before I try to hide or show it. I got this behavior while debugging using Google Developer tools but I'm not sure if it's the "real why".

Are you dynamically creating that element for example with `$().append()` or similar? If so, make sure that you actually create the element before you try to interact with it. If the element is not created dynamically, make sure that the code that interacts with the element is inside the `$(document).ready` or `$(window).on('load')` callback.

> No matter where I put socket.on('connected'.. because it's always called after console.log('Ready'). Based on this, my theory of F5 refresh is not correct and I feel that I'm running in circles.

This happens because establishing the socket connection takes more time than to render the DOM. It's generally good idea to attach the event listener as soon as possible to not miss any events. If you attach the event listener only after the DOM has loaded, you *might* miss some events. But be aware, that if you manipulate the DOM inside the event listener callback, then you cannot be sure that the DOM is loaded and your target element is there, unless you attach the event listener after the DOM has loaded. So I recommend to attach event listeners after the DOM has loaded. At least those that contains some code to modify the DOM.

> Anyone have an idea why HTML elements are not present sometimes?

There are not many possible reasons for this. Either your elements are not yet loaded or your code has removed them for some reason. I suggest putting breakpoints to the places where you create the elements or manipulate them somehow and see what the execution order is.

> And, If I use socket.on('anyevent, {}) inside $(document).ready(function(){} do I have any guarantee that the event will only be processed after page being full rendered?

You have a guarantee that the callback function will be executed when the `anyevent` occurs and when the DOM is ready, that is, all the static html elements are there.